# Does there exist an integrable or bounded holomorphic function in the unit disk that cannot be analytically continued past the disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can one construct a holomorphic function $f$ in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}=\{|z|<1\}$ such that $f$ is integrable and that $f$ can't be continued analytically across any subarc of $\partial \mathbb{D}$ ?  If it exists, then can one construct such a function which is also bounded?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. [Hadamard's Gap Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%E2%80%93Hadamard_gap_theorem) facilitates the construction of a bounded holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ which cannot be continued analytically across any subarc of $\partial \mathbb{D}$.

The power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^n+1}}{2^n+1}$ has radius of convergence $1$. Define
$$
f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{C}\quad z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^n+1}}{2^n+1}.
$$
Then $f$ is a bounded holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$. The derivative $f'(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2^n}\ (z\in \mathbb{D})$ has $\partial \mathbb{D}$ as its [natural boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation#Natural_boundary), which shows that $f$ has $\partial \mathbb{D}$ as its natural boundary. So the function $f$ answers your question.

Comment: By the way, do you know what properties should a holomorphic $f$ have such that it can be continued analycally across a subarc of $\partial \mathbb{D}$?